# Proving $x^n\cdot x ^m=x^{n+m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x\in \mathbb F \backslash {0}$  and $n,m\in \mathbb Z$
How does one show that $x^n\cdot x ^m=x^{n+m}$

I thought about induction but struggling with it because of the fields.

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $z^n$?

Comment: $z^n=z^{n-1} \cdot z^1$  for all $n\in \mathbb N $

Comment: So $z^{n-1}\cdot{z^{1}}=z^{n-1+1}=z^n$, right?

Comment: Well it's not the case. it's about integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:** For every $m \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, $x^n\cdot x^m = x^{n+m}$.

**Proof:** *Base Case:* $x^n \cdot x^0 = x^n \cdot 1 = x^n = x^{n+0}$.

*Inductive Step:* Suppose $x^n\cdot x^{m-1} = x^{n+m-1}$ for some $m \ge 1$. Then $x^n \cdot x^m = x^n \cdot (x^{m-1} \cdot x) = (x^n \cdot x^{m-1}) \cdot x = x^{n+m-1} \cdot x = x^{n+m-1+1} = x^{n+m}$.

**Claim:** For every $m \in \{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$, $x^n\cdot x^m = x^{n+m}$.

**Proof:** *Base Case:* Same as above.

*Inductive Step:* Suppose $x^n \cdot x^m = x^{n+m}$ for some $m \le 0$. Then $x^n \cdot x^{m-1} = x^n \cdot x^{m-1} \cdot 1 = x^n \cdot x^{m-1} \cdot x \cdot x^{-1} = x^n \cdot x^m \cdot x^{-1} = x^{n+m} \cdot x^{-1} = x^{n+m-1}$.

Comment: But the case for Z is the case i'm struggling with. It's easy for $\mathbb N$

Comment: What is the trick to apply the same to negative numbers?

Comment: @user21312 Edited